# Asp.Net Date Picker Control from the Text Box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 2 Text box accepting date from the calender control. One is From & another is To.
I would like take the date accordingly as follows.

On the 1st text box(from),It can only take the today & any other Previous date.
But, the 2nd text box(To),It takes the today date & it should take the date not less than the date which is taken on the 1st text box.

how can i do this  in .net.
This is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"   Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#txtfrom").datepicker({ maxDate:0 });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txtto").datepicker({});
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker { font-size:8pt !important}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="demo">
<b>From:</b> <asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server" />
&nbsp &nbsp

<b>To:</b><asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My first text box is working properly.But Can you help on the codeing of 2nd text box.

Comment: Basically, you handle the onSelect event.
When a date is selected, check to see if it's before today's date and first calender date.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your datepickers like this:

```
        $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });

        $("#txtTo").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
```

What it effectively is doing is to change the `option` `minDate` and `maxDate` for *txtFrom* and *txtTo* respectively, when the date is selected in the datepicker.

Comment: i am using the java script date picker.So,I think the onselect:functon is not use here.

Comment: From the code you posted, it seems that you ARE using jQuery UI DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `{}` in

```
$("#txtto").datepicker({});
```

I think.

Comment: In this script i have to give the condition.Here I can give the condition through which it can take today date.

Comment: But,I don't know how it should compare the date with the 1st text box, Which won't take less than the 1st text Box.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new rows as you have done for to date:

```
$(function () {
  $('[id$=txtTo]').datepicker();
  $('[id$=txtFrom]').datepicker();
});
```

And there is no need to Use **{}** 
if you want to add ranges then try the below code:

```
$('[id$=txtFrom]').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('[id$=txtTo]').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $('[id$=txtFrom]').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('[id$=txtFrom]').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's A nice code. But,I would like to Compare the date between these 2text boxes. On the 1st text box it take the previous date up to today. But,On the 2nd text box it take the date which should not less than the 1st text box & take the date up to Today.